# What is the purpose of .black domains?

Tags: domains, domain-registration, top-level-domains

I know that each top-level domain has its own story behind (country, organisation, company, etc).

But what is the story of [.black](http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/black.html) domain? What kind of people would register `.black`?
What people would expect to find on the websites with that top-level domain? If so, why there is no `.white`? Won't we end up with other color names soon?

Comment: All these added extensions are just adding up to .dumb as indicated by Network Solutions new hopeful revenue extender of the week. Having .infinity new TLDs is just kind of crackerjack.

Answer (score 1):

It could be used, for example, for black themed webpages, like google. A black themed website saves battery as the screens have not to bright

example: http://googleblack.magic-pack.com/